# two dimensional char array in a structure gets overwritten while looping

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am having a struct defined like this:

```
typedef struct stringd{
    char *y;
    char *x[32];
}stringd;
```

in the main program I am declaring a pointer to stringd as shown:

```
stringd *d = malloc(sizeof(*d));
```

in the main function I am parsing an input string and then storing it in a two dimensional char array

```
char *c[32];
```

Whenever I encounter a '|' character in my input string I copy the items of c to *x[32] in stringd structure. as shown below:

```
if (c[i][0]=='\174')
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
        d[k].x[j]=c[j]; 
        c[j]=NULL;
    }
k++;
```

once the last string from the input(Delimiter is the space) is fetched I do the final copy of array c to x in stringd as shown(token is the pointer to the input string);

```
if(*token == '\0'||*token=='\n' 
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
        d[k].x[j]=c[j];
    }
```

the problem here is the strings stored earlier in the struct char array x gets overwritten by junk characters upon the last operation. Where am I going wrong?

any help appreciated,

Comment: Do you ever allocate memory for the objects that y and x[] of stringd point to? Same question for c[]. If not, you are corrupting memory, possibly where some other objects are located.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the code you posted is run in that exact order, here's what I'm seeing:

You allocated only one `stringd` object. But then you increment `k` after your first loop. So in your final if-statement, you're accessing `d[k]` which is past what you allocated.

So if I'm reading this right, this is undefined behavior since you're writing into unallocated memory.

Comment: guessed that.Thanks. Does this mean I cannot use a pointer to my struct or is there a way to allocate memory separately for every d[k]?

Comment: You can allocate an array of them in your malloc: `stringd *d = malloc(sizeof(*d) * n);` where `n` is the number of them you want.